# oracle sql to get min timestamp when the count of results large than a number

Tags: sql, oracle

in order to improve the performance, I need a sql to implement the following requirement.

If there is a table and has the following column:

```
id timestamp value
```

How can I get the min timestamp(e.g. :t1) when the count of the result > 100000 ?

then the following sql result--count(*)  will > 100000

```
select count(*) from table where  timestamp < :t1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of your question is: Find the earliest timestamp in the table for which there are at least 100,000 earlier rows.

There are probably many ways to do it; the main difficulty is trying to come up with an efficient one.

I think an analytic-function approach is most likely to work well.  The most obvious choice is to use COUNT:

```
select min(timestamp) from (
  select timestamp, count(*) over (order by timestamp rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) earlier_rows
  from table
)
where earlier_rows >= 100000
```

But I suspect using RANK or something similar will be faster:

```
select min(timestamp) from (
  select timestamp, rank() over (order by timestamp) time_rank
  from table
)
where time_rank > 100000
```

I'm not sure off the top of my head, but these may give slightly different results if there are duplicate timestamps.

Comment: but the query takes me 6 seconds

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the min and max value and the count

```
select 
    count(t.*), 
    min(t.timestamp),
    max(t.timestamp)
from table t
where ( select count(*) from table t where  t.timestamp < :t1 ) > 10000
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, the condition > 100000 is missing

Comment: Aggregate functions are not allowed in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Yes was trying to be quick and copy the first part  of the query in the where.  this is going to run the query twice though as it get all the records for the where select statement and again for the actual query, think it would be better to run the query like below and check the result in whatever your running the query in to check if its over 10000

select 
    count(t.*), 
    min(t.timestamp),
    max(t.timestamp)
from table t
 t.timestamp < :t1